# How to contribute to a project if there is no access to it?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a private gitlab repository.
I know the usual ways to contribute to a repository.
However in this question I would like to ask a bit of creative thinking. For reasons that are non-technical , a group of developers that are contributing to the project *do not* have access to the repository so I would like to ask about ways to allow that they contribute to the project

The obvious answer would be "give them access", and if that is the case, can I give them *only* permission to `git pull` and `git clone`?

And if that is not permitted what other ways are there. So far the organization gives them zip files of everything that has been worked and they worked on that.

Comment: _"the organization gives them zip files"_ <blink>

Comment: @AlexHowansky I suppose the reason it gives them zip files is because the organization wants them to work on something *only* when it feels work needs to be done. But I didnt make the rules so it is just a guess

Answer (score 1):

In GitLab, adding a member with role *Reporter* gives only read access to the repository. I.e. `clone` and `pull` are allowed, but no write access like `push`

Answer (score 1):

Adrian points it out correctly. I'd like to add some more to that.
In GitLab, you can either restrict/protect a branch in the same repo or you can restrict the repo itself.

For a protected branch, you can select the branch you want to protect, and then you can select individuals who will be able to `push` to that branch, anyone apart from that list will have access to the repository but won't be able to modify that branch

For a protected repo, if you give `reporter` permission to your users, they can `fork` the project, work on it, and raise a merge request to any branch. But only people who have permission level of Developer or higher can merge the merge requests.

You can follow this link for the same: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/authorization_for_merge_requests.html

Comment: You can choose which roles are allowed to merge when protecting a branch. That is usually mantainers, but _can_ be developers+maintainers.

Answer (score 0):

Run a parallel git repository.  At appropriate points, authorized master repository developers push to the master git repository and push key commit stages to the secondary.  The secondary repository could even be locked at times if the company wished to block development sometimes.

In terms of the people side of development, it would seem to be comfortable and that would encourage development activity.

Perhaps such a very simple solution might be enough, on the principle of only do as much as is needed and don't create structures that might not be needed down the road.

I am only a beginner git at the moment, but it seems to me that perhaps the separateness does not need to be greatly formalized at this point in the mysterious project.  However it could also easily be that it is large or has other factors compelling a more formal approach like Danish Aziz recommends.

But even a simple parallel repository would be a step up from communicating by zip files.